# Soap Request using java - Request call format issue

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client, wsdl2java

I'm trying to make a SOAP call with this Java code:

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("UserAuthentication", serverURI);
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("UserAuthentication", "UserAuthentication");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("user_name", "UserAuthentication");
soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("pqr@xyz.com");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("password", "UserAuthentication");
soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

The required format of SOAP call (I'm trying to generate) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UserAuthentication xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <user_name>string</user_name>
      <password>string</password>
    </UserAuthentication>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the actual call generated by my code doesn't match the required format and is rejected at the receiving end, and I'm trying to figure out why and how to fix it:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:UserAuthentication="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/Logininfo.asmx?op=UserAuthentication">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<UserAuthentication:UserAuthentication>
<UserAuthentication:user_name>pqr@xyz.com</UserAuthentication:user_name>
<UserAuthentication:password>123</UserAuthentication:password>
</UserAuthentication:UserAuthentication>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message from the receiving end?

In any case, the namespaces for the `UserAuthentication` elements differ.

Expected: `http://tempuri.org/`
Actual: `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/Logininfo.asmx?op=UserAuthentication`

Comment: Error comes for Client Header issue

Comment: Can you get more specific?

Comment: Response :  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xml
ns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Bod
y><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not reco
gnize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .</faultstring><detail/></soap:Fault>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: The `SOAPAction` HTTP header is not send in the payload (the XML) but as a header. Please add the code you're using to send the `SOAPEnvelope` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("UserAuthentication", serverURI);
```

Why are you adding that namespace when given you desired request it is not needed?

Try removing that line. Then this one:

```
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("UserAuthentication", "UserAuthentication");
```

Make it:

```
QName bodyName = new QName("http://tempuri.org/",
    "UserAuthentication", "m");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement(bodyName);
```